# PDF Kit + wkhtmltopdf-binary PDF shrink issue on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfkit, wkhtmltopdf-binary

I'm using `gem 'pdfkit'` and `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'` to generate the invoices on the Ruby on Rails app. I've a **erb** file, I'm rendering it as follow:

```
    kit = PDFKit.new(ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string('billing/invoice_pdf', layout: nil, locals: { invoice: invoice_data }), pdf_option)
    file = kit.to_file("#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{@invoice.id}_#{@invoice.remote_id}.pdf")
    @invoice.document = Document.create(file: file)
```

and the `pdf_option` is

```
  def pdf_option
    {
      disable_smart_shrinking: false,
      page_size:               'A4',
      margin_top:              '0',
      margin_right:            '0',
      margin_bottom:           '0',
      margin_left:             '0',
      encoding:                'UTF-8'
    }
  end
```

The generated pdf looks good on local machine, however it gets weird on the production server.

This one is the local machine pdf
[image: Local machine pdf]

and this one is from production
[image]

Any idea? what could be the wrong? Thank you

Comment: How does it look when you run local production?

Comment: @anothermh It looks as in first image

Comment: There are some issues about Linux and dpi, like this https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3287 . You have to inspect your prod/local OS difference, wkhtmltopdf version etc.

Comment: I'm guessing you're working on a Mac? I had to apply a different zoom while working locally, and even then, it was still different from working on Linux.